# How to get data from table (parsing) where data is not in html body?

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

Here is a link https://en-parsante.solutions/?module=table
And when i refresh the page and look in network, i saw json data. link - https://en-parsante.solutions/data.json

In this json i have that's data but this data is hashed.
So, can everyone tell me how can get data from that's table?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with *this data is hashed*? It doesn't look like the JSON contains the data from the first link ...

Comment: i mean when you go to the developer tools. and then go network, refreshing page you can see the data.json (fetch/xhr). Secand link means, when you click to data.json you go the new link which spelled [link](https://en-parsante.solutions/data.json). And here is have data from table